# Sending results of MongoDB find() using Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to NodeJS and I am trying to connect to MongoDB I prepared a query and I can see the output on server by traversing the cursor. But I want to send the output of find() to response.

```
var cursor = db.collection('dbLocations').find(
     {$and: [
        {type: locationType}, 
        {createdAt : { "$gte": new Date(createdAt), "$lt": date1 }}
      ]}).skip(skip).limit(count);
```

Now I am getting error like 
`Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` if I do a string concate and then JSON.stringify
I tried pretty() but it gives me error `skip(...).limit(...).toString(...).pretty is not a function
or skip(...).limit(...).pretty is not a function`.
I am totally unable to figure out how to convert as I am not clear about the concept of callback() and all solutions have that. Is there a simple stringify, parse or pretty kind of solution to it.
Below is my express snippet for get, it looks very messy right now. I want to send the find() output instead of random stuff.

```
app.get('/api/first', function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    var locationType = request.body.type;
    var createdAt = request.body.createdAt;
    //var pageNumber = parseInt(request.body.pageNumber);
    console.log(locationType);
    console.log(createdAt);
    //console.log(pageNumber);
    var date1 = new Date(createdAt);
    date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
    var count = 2;
    var str="";
    var skip;
    if(request.body.pageNumber)
        skip = parseInt((request.body.pageNumber-1)*count);
    else
        skip = 0;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected');
    var db = client.db('locationapi');
    var cursor = db.collection('dbLocations').find(
         {$and: [
            {type: locationType}, 
            {createdAt : {"$gte": new Date(createdAt), "$lt": date1}}
         ]}
      ).skip(skip).limit(count);

        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {

        if(err) throw err;
     if(doc !== null) {
      console.log(doc); str=str+doc;
     } else client.close();
    });
    client.close();
  });
   var myObj = {
      name: 'jgj',
      job: 'Ninja'
    };   // random stuff
    response.end(JSON.stringify(myObj));
});
```

Comment: To what response.  Are you using express or something else?

Comment: Yes I am using express

Comment: You should post your express code also then.

Comment: As for express, you should be able to simply do `response.send(myObj);`.  No need for  `response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`

Comment: I understand.  Just check with static object first.

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection('dbLocations').find({
  $and: [{
    type: locationType
  }, {
    createdAt: {
      "$gte": new Date(createdAt),
      "$lt": date1
    }
  }]
}, {
  skip: skip, 
  limit: count
}).toArray(function (err, docs) { 
  if (err) return res.status(500).send({error: err})
  res.send(docs)
});
```

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Collection.html#find

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Cursor.html#toArray